# "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'." error in Photo: why and how do I fix it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code below gives the error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'."

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{               
    if (fpPhoto.HasFile)         
    {             
        if (fpPhoto.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/jpg" 
            || fpPhoto.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/jpeg" 
            || fpPhoto.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/png") 
        {               
            int filelenght = fpPhoto.PostedFile.ContentLength;  
            imagebytes = fpPhoto.FileBytes;   
            //fpPhoto.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(imagebytes, 0, filelenght);   
        }        
    }      
    User objUser = new User();  

    objUser.UserName_Pk = txtUserName.Text; 
    objUser.Password = txtPassword.Text;    
    objUser.MobileNo = txtMobileNo.Text;    
    objUser.Email = txtEmail.Text;        
    objUser.SecurityAnswer = txtAnswer.Text;        
    objUser.Photo = Convert.ToByte( imagebytes);
```

Why do I get this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: post proper indent code...

Comment: whet is the type of your Photo ???

Comment: I declared photo in entity as
 public byte Photo {get;set;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that `imageBytes` is an array of bytes (`byte[]`). As your code compiles, the `Photo` property must be of type `byte`. You try to convert the byte array to a single byte in this line:

```
objUser.Photo = Convert.ToByte( imagebytes);
```

This leads to an exception as the byte array does not implement `IConvertible` which would be required in order for the conversion to work. But how would you want to convert a byte array to a single byte anyway? How should the conversion mechanism know which byte of the array to assign to the single byte? Therefore I suspect that you'd rather want the `Photo` property to also be of type `byte[]` so that it is able to store the complete picture and not only one byte of it.

So in order to fix this, try to change the property in your Entity to `byte[]` (which might also involve changing the database schema) and assign the array directly without using `Convert.ToByte()`.

Comment: When i changed the Entity as a byte[] than its give error.... Cannot implicitly convert type byte to byte[]

Comment: @user3339971: Which error?

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type byte to byte[]

Comment: @MohammadAaquil: Is the 'Convert.ToByte()' still there? You need to remove it as there is not need to convert `byte[]` to `byte[]`.

Comment: @MohammadAaquil: good to hear that it helped. Please consider accepting the answer if it was helpful.