# Bytes to byte[] conversion?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am storing an image after converting it to bytes in SQL Server but there occurs a problem i.e unable to convert from bytes to bytes[].
Here is the code, please send your valuable reply.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (fpPhoto.HasFile)
    {
        if (fpPhoto.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/jpg" || 
            fpPhoto.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/jpeg" || 
            fpPhoto.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/png")
        {
            byte[] imagebytes = new byte[fpPhoto.PostedFile.ContentLength];
            int filelenght = fpPhoto.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            imagebytes = fpPhoto.FileBytes;
            fpPhoto.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(imagebytes, 0, filelenght);
        }
    }

    User objUser = new User();

    objUser.UserName_Pk = txtUserName.Text;
    objUser.Password = txtPassword.Text;
    objUser.MobileNo = txtMobileNo.Text;
    objUser.Email = txtEmail.Text;
    objUser.SecurityAnswer = txtAnswer.Text;
    objUser.Photo = Convert.ToByte(imagebytes); // Here Error occurs

    objUserBll.InsertUpdate(objUser);
}
```

Comment: Which line you got the error?

Comment: What data type is `objUser.Photo` ?

Comment: What is the datatype for Photo ?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: It obvoiusly is a byte[], as Markus answered below having just replied to similar question, and if you look at that other question, it is identical .. which makes one wonder if they are the same??

Comment: the error is probably just saying that imagebytes is undeclared, because it is declared inside the if block, and would be out of scope on the line he is trying to use it on...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

If Photo datatype is `byte[]`

```
   objUser.Photo= BitConverter.GetBytes(imagebytes);
```

Comment: If they are `byte[]`, why does he need to do that? ... imagebytes is already `byte[]`

Comment: If it works, Then please accept my answer. It's helps to others

Answer (score 0):

As `imagebytes` should already be a byte array (`byte[]`), you don't need to convert it. Just remove the `Convert.ToByte()`and you're good to go:

```
objUser.Photo = imagebytes;
```

If `Photo` is not an array of bytes yet, I suggest that you change its data type to `byte[]` as you obviously want to save a Photo which usually means storing binary data.

Also, have a look at the declaration of the variable named `imagebytes` in the `if`block at the beginning. In order to use the variable for the assignment at the end, you need to move the declaration outside the `if` block, so that the variable is declared before. The following code should be enough (in its current form, you create a new array that you overwrite immediately afterwards when you assign `FileBytes`to it):

```
// Declare variable outside of first if block
byte[] imagebytes; 
if (fpPhoto.HasFile)
{
    // ...
```

BTW: I've just answered a very similar question with an almost identical piece of code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21951226/642579). Maybe you find something useful there. As the code is almost identical and the questions have been posed in the same timeframe, I suspect that this is homework. In this case, do yourself the favor and make sure that you really understand the tasks and their solutions, even if the answers on SO help you to solve some issues.